# wordpress woocommerce variable product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have use WooCommerce and WooCommerce Min/Max Quantities plugin

I want like this if "minimum quantity" is 50 and "in stock" is 40 than product is out of stock but I have to do all 40 quantity is in input box and add to cart. this is working well in "simple product" but when in "variable product" 
its not working.

```
Array
(
[variation_id] => 5
[variation_is_visible] => 1
[variation_is_active] => 1
[is_purchasable] => 1
[display_price] => 54
[display_regular_price] => 54
[attributes] => Array
    (
        [attribute_color] => red
    )

[image_src] => 
[image_link] => 
[image_title] => 
[image_alt] => 
[image_srcset] => 
[image_sizes] => 
[price_html] => £54.00
[availability_html] => 

10 In stock

[sku] => abc
[weight] =>  kg
[dimensions] => 
[min_qty] => 40
[max_qty] => 10
[backorders_allowed] => 
[is_in_stock] => 1
[is_downloadable] => 
[is_virtual] => 
[is_sold_individually] => no
[variation_description] => 
[input_value] => 40
)
```

This is comes from file `woocommerce/template/simple-product/add-to-cart/variable.php`.

The code below is custom code and placed above form in original file and this code is referencing from where to above array comes.

```
print_r($variation);
```

> where attribute/array [input_value] => 40 is not found in woocommerce/include/class-wc-product-variable.php

I have assigned [input_value] => 40 to 10

please help

Comment: yes thanks mbacon40 for edit my question